Bash / SED: Delete all lines that have white space between two characters
I have a file that I need to start
path:*/Application Stuff/hey/ #team1
path:*/Application/things/ #team2

I'm trying to use sed to delete the lines that have a white space between the ... values.

The following works on your example:
sed '/ [^ ].* #/d'


/.../ is an address. The command following it is only run if the regular expression matches.
The command is d, i.e. delete.
The regex means space, not a space, then anything up to a space followed by an octothorpe.

