Only modify whitespace if it's between two characters?
This
sed -i "" 's/\ /\\ /' "$SENTRY_OUTPUT_LOCATION"

will turn this
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/The\ Tests/Test.Test.swift* @team1
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/The\ Tests/SecondTest.Test.swift* @team1
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/TestActions/ThirdTest.swift* @team1

into
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/The\\ Tests/Test.Test.swift* @team1
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/The\\ Tests/SecondTest.Test.swift* @team1
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/TestActions/ThirdTest.swift*\ @team1

In this case I only want to add the \ if the whitespace is between the two *. Notice the last line there is a \ between the * and @team1 that doesn't belong.

Regular expressions are not good at matching something only between other things.

You could do this in a programming language, because they allow you to use a function as the replacement, and the function can do a nested replacement. But it's difficult in sed.

sed -E 's#(\w)\\([[:space:]]+)(\w)#\1\\\\\2\3#' file ??

What @David said, but I suspect you want the global flag too sed 's/.../.../g'?

Expected output is usually more helpful then the description of what you are trying to do.

@DavidC.Rankin Where is the * characters in your pattern?

this smells like a reincarnation of one of your previous q's (which was closed due to lack of interaction... ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78903250/bash-sed-delete-all-lines-that-have-white-space-between-two-characters AND further continued in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78903732/bash-sed-greedy-vs-non-greedy

You don't seem to be learning anything from the answers to your previous questions. Rather than keeping asking for every next thing you want to do, really think about the answers you get and if there's anything about one you don't understand then ask about it in a comment under the answer and then you'll learn enough to not have to keep asking questions about every little thing.

Your previous questions had a blank after path: - are you changing that to a * now to try to make it easier to find the next space in the line? If so, don't, it's not necessary and could lead to a worse solution than if the space was present.

@Barmar - it's there, just negated by not being a \w (word) character.

You can only do this "gracefully" with perl - perl -pe 's/\*[^*]*\*/$&=~s| |\\ |gr/ge'

@DavidC.Rankin They said "between * characters", you interpreted that as "between any alphanumeric characters"?

@Barmar - my bad, correct you are -- I totally missed that point.

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():
$ awk 'match($0,/([^*]*\*)(.*)(\*.*)/,a) { $0=a[1] gensub(/ /,"\\\\ ","g",a[2]) a[3] } 1' file
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/The\\ Tests/Test.Test.swift* @team1
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/The\\ Tests/SecondTest.Test.swift* @team1
path:*/Tests/XCUITests/TestActions/ThirdTest.swift* @team1


This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;s/^([^*]*([*][^* ]*[*][^*]*)*[*][^* ]*) ([^*]*[*])/\1\\\n\3/;ta
        y/\n/ /' file

In order to replace a space or spaces between *'s we first must discount pairs of *'s with no spaces preceding such strings. By replacing the intended space with a newline allows the regexp to proceed to the end of line where apon the newlines can be translated back into spaces.
In the above regexp I have used [*] to represent * as this is preferable to \*.
N.B. The OP used s/\ /\\ / to replace a space by a backslash and a space, where s/ /\\ / would have the same result. In the first expression the \ on the LHS of the substitution just escapes the space and does not represent a backslash if that was intended.

Sounds like an X/Y problem.
With the info given, you should just be able to loop over it.
$ cat x
path: */Tests/XCUITests/The Tests/Test.Test.swift* @team1
path: */Tests/XCUITests/The Tests/SecondTest.Test.swift* @team1
path: */Tests/XCUITests/TestActions/ThirdTest.swift* @team1
path: */Tests/Other* Tests/My Test Actions/4th  Test.swift* @team1
path: * space after first of multiple asterisks * ...

$ sed -E 's,[*]([[:space:]].*[*]),\*\\\1,;:x;s,([*].*[^\])([[:space:]])(.*[*]),\1\\\2\3,;t x' x
path: */Tests/XCUITests/The\ Tests/Test.Test.swift* @team1
path: */Tests/XCUITests/The\ Tests/SecondTest.Test.swift* @team1
path: */Tests/XCUITests/TestActions/ThirdTest.swift* @team1
path: */Tests/Other*\ Tests/My\ Test\ Actions/4th\ \ Test.swift* @team1
path: *\ space\ after\ first\ of\ multiple\ asterisks\ * ...

s,[*]([[:space:]].*[*]),\*\\\1, quotes any space after the FIRST asterisk to prevent the need for Perl-ish lookbehinds.
:x establishes a labelled point for returns.
s,([*].*[^\])([[:space:]])(.*[*]),\1\\\2\3, adds a backslash in front of ONE space that doesn't have one already, and
t x branches back to x if there was a substitution done, so...
it quotes each space until they are all done, then falls through.

For this particular case sed -Ee 's@(\*.*) (.*\*)@\1\\ \2@g' input_file is enough I hope.

But despite of fact that it is technically possible to solve it with sed's hold spaces, you need to know it is still quite difficult and noone does such cases with sed - sed is totally different paradigm than structural ones like C where you can define sequence of steps based on if condition therefore solve many subcases. Sed was not designed for subcases.

Using @ as the delimiter when there's a potentially relevant @ in the input makes your script more confusing than it has to be. Just replace the @s with :s or #s or similar.

Not my downvote btw, my answer was downvoted too. I suspect they all were.
